# Understanding infinitely many primes proof.

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Why does it follow that $p_i$ must divide $P-p_1p_1...p_n$?

[image]

Comment: $P$ has a prime factorization. If there are only a finite number of primes, $P$ must be divisible by some prime, which is among $p_1, ..., p_n$

Comment: Because if $P$ weren't prime then it would be composite.  Since $P>p_i$ for all $i$ if there were only finitely many primes it follows that $P$ would necessarily be composite then and so is the product of some collection of primes.

Comment: If a number $a$ divides two numbers $b$ and $c$, then $a$ divides the difference $b-c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) (which is usually proved before the infinitude of primes) every integer greater than $1$ either is a prime number itself or can be represented as the product of prime numbers.

Comment: Actually what Euclid uses is [Elements VII.31](https://www.claymath.org/library/historical/euclid/files/elem.7.31.html) which says that every composite number is measured by (i.e. divisible by) some prime.

Answer (score 1):

Because $P$ is greater than the putative greatest prime, it must be composite, and is thus divisible by some $p_i$. Because $p_i$ is included in the product $p_1 \dots p_n$, it divides $p_1 \dots p_n$. Then, $p_i$ divides both $P$ and $p_1 \dots p_n$, so $p_i$ divides their difference.